# An inequality leading into Pell's Equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I need to show that for $\alpha$ irrational there are infinite coprime pairs $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have that
$$\vert{\alpha-\frac{x}y}\vert\leqslant\frac{1}{y^2}$$
Hints are also appreciated

Comment: Hint : use the convergents of the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$. Do you know about continued fractions ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I do know about continued fractions but alpha is any irrational number for which we knwo nothing about its continued fractional approximation

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction (especially theorem 5)

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
(x^2-dy^2)(u^2-dv^2)
&=x^2u^2+d^2y^2v^2-d(x^2v^2+y^2u^2)\\
&=x^2u^2\pm 2dxuyv+d^2y^2v^2-d(x^2v^2\pm2xuyv+y^2u^2)\\
&=(xu\pm dyv)^2-d(xv\pm yu)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Choosing the "+" sign,
$(x^2-dy^2)(u^2-dv^2)
=(xu+ dyv)^2-d(xv+ yu)^2
$.

Therefore,
if
$u^2-du^2=1$,
we can get
successively larger solutions to
$x^2-dy^2=1$
by
$x_1=u, y_1=v,
x_{n+1}=ux_n+dvy_n,
y_{n+1}=vx_n+uy_n
$.

For $d=2$,
since
$3^2-2\cdot 2^2=1$,
the values are
$x_1=3, y_1=2,
x_{n+1}=3x_n+4y_n,
y_{n+1}=2x_n+3y_n
$.

To get a more rapidly convergent sequence,
use
$x_1=u, y_1=v,
x_{n+1}=x_n^2+dy_n^2,
y_{n+1}=2x_ny_n
$
so that
$x_{n+1}^2-dy_{n+1}^2,
=(x_n^2-dy_n^2)^2
$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a consequence of Dirichlet’s Approximation Theorem which is: 
$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R},\forall n\in \mathbb{N^*},\exists (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times \{1,..,n\}/ \lvert{\alpha-\frac{x}{y}}\rvert < \frac {1}{yn}$$
Proof of this theorem, let $(a_i)_{i\in \{0,..,n\}}/\forall i\in \{0,..,n\},a_i=i\alpha-\lfloor{i\alpha}\rfloor $, and let $(J_i)_{i\in\{0,..,n-1\}}/\forall i \in \{0,..,n-1\},J_i=[\frac {i}{n} \frac{i+1}{n}[$.

We have $\forall i \in \{0,..,n\},0\le a_i<1$ and $(J_i)_{i\in\{0,..,n-1\}}$ is a partition of the interval $[0,1[$, but we have $(J_i)_{i\in\{0,..,n-1\}}$ is a family of $n$ intervals and $(a_i)_{i\in \{0,..,n\}}$ is a family of $n+1$ reals, so by applying the pigeonhole principle:

$$\exists i,j\in\{0..n\},\exists k \in \{0,..,n-1\} /(a_i,a_j)\in J_k^2 \text{ and } i< j$$
So we have $$\lvert{a_j-a_i}\rvert < \lvert{\sup J_k-\inf J_k}\rvert\implies\lvert{a_j-a_i}\rvert<\frac 1 n$$
We can find that:
$$a_j-a_i=(j-i)\alpha- (\lfloor{j\alpha}\rfloor-\lfloor{i\alpha}\rfloor)$$
By setting $(x,y)=(\lfloor{j\alpha}\rfloor-\lfloor{i\alpha}\rfloor,j-i)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, we have that $y\in \{ 1,..,n \}$ because $0 \le i < j \le n$.

So this theorem is proven, an immediate consequence is $\lvert{\alpha-\frac{x}{y}}\rvert < \frac {1}{y^2}$ by noting that $0<y\le n\implies \frac 1 {ny}\le \frac 1 {y^2}$.

Now From here we will suppose that $\alpha$ is irrational.
Furthermore, let's suppose that for $\alpha$ there is only a finite number of coprime pairs $x,y\in \mathbb{Z^*}$ such that:  $\lvert{\alpha-\frac{x}{y}}\rvert < \frac {1}{y^2}$
Let $E$ be the set of all such coprime pairs, and $K=\{\frac x y ,(x,y)\in E\}$.

We have $\alpha\neq p \quad\forall p\in K\implies \lvert{\alpha-p}\rvert\neq 0 \quad\forall p\in K$.
But we have $K$ is a finite set, there must be an $n\in \mathbb{N}/\frac 1 n<\lvert{\alpha-p}\rvert \quad\forall p\in K$
but we know that $\exists (x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}\times\{1,..,n\}/\lvert{\alpha-\frac x y}\rvert< \frac 1 {yn}\le\frac 1 n$ which is a contradiction.

Conclusion:$$\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q},\exists^\infty (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{N^*}/ \lvert{\alpha-\frac{x}{y}}\rvert < \frac {1}{y^2} \text{ and } \gcd(x,y)=1$$